# Are there any artifacts that tap for white, blue or black mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I'm looking for artifacts similar to the crystals from the Ikoria set (e.g. [Indatha Crystal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Indatha%20Crystal)) or the banners (e.g. [Abzan Banner](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abzan%20Banner)), but instead that produce white, blue or black mana.

I'm not opposed to lands either like [Arcane Sanctum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcane%20Sanctum) but I'm more interested in finding artifacts for my [Alela, Artful Provocateur](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alela%2C%20Artful%20Provocateur) Commander deck.

Comment: Shards of Alara had a cycle 3 mana artifacts that tapped shard colors. I cannot remember there names though

Comment: @NeilMeyer Obelisk of [Shard name] in this case Obelisk of Esper

Answer (score 21):

Scryfall offers a `produces:` operator that returns cards that produce the mana you ask for. It takes into account statements like “add N mana of any color” as well as treasure production and the ability to produce additional mana (like [Heartbeat of Spring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heartbeat%20of%20Spring)).

- If you give `produces:` a set of mana types out of `WUBRGC`—the five colors plus colorless—it returns cards that produce at least those types of mana, possibly including others.
- If you give it a number, it returns cards that produce *exactly* that number of types of mana. `produces:6` is the maximum, which is all the cards that produce WUBRG and also colorless.
- `produces:any` finds cards that produce any type of mana at all. (It's equivalent to `produces>=1`.)

These would be your primary options when searching for Esper mana generators the way you are:

- Most helpful: `produces:w or produces:u or produces:b` will find cards that individually produce at least any of those colors, possibly including other colors and/or colorless.
- `produces:wub` will find cards that individually produce at least white, blue, *and* black—a card that produces just one or two of these won't match. You can also do `produces:esper` for this result.
- `produces:any commander:wub` will find Esper cards that produce at least one type of mana, no matter what it is, but it will also match cards that only produce colorless mana.

You've requested artifacts that *tap* for mana, but there are artifacts like [Altar of Shadows](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Altar%20of%20Shadows) and [Caged Sun](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Caged%20Sun) that produce mana without requiring being tapped for it. Since Alela doesn't interact specifically with tapping/untapping artifacts, it seems these may work well for you too.

I suggest one of these searches:

- If you want artifacts that produce at least one of those colors: [`(produces:w or produces:u or produces:b) format:commander type:artifact commander:wub`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28produces%3Aw+or+produces%3Au+or+produces%3Ab%29+format%3Acommander+type%3Aartifact+commander%3Awub+&unique=cards)
- If you want only those artifacts capable of producing *all* of those colors, like [Obelisk of Esper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Obelisk%20of%20Esper): [`produces:wub format:commander type:artifact commander:wub`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=produces%3Awub+format%3Acommander+type%3Aartifact+commander%3Awub+&unique=cards)

---

#### Technical notes on the `produces:` operator

The `produces:` operator can also take different comparators: `produces>`, `>=`, `=`, `<=`, or `<`.

When you're supplying a set of colors, `produces:` is equal to `produces>=` (at least equal to this set).

When you're supplying a number, `produces:` is equal to `produces=` (exactly this number).

This is fairly typical of Scryfall operators that take numbers and/or mana: if you see `:` followed by digits or a number of sets of mana, usually that operator will take some set of `>=<` too. The `:` case will default to the behaviour that's the most common or intuitive search for that operator.

Comment: Looks like Obelisk of Esper is the only one that explicitly produces only those colours, though, instead of producing any colour.

Comment: @nick012000 Oh, yeah, I hadn't actually taken a look at that list. [Also Dromar's Attendant](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aartifact+produces%3Desper). Only two artifacts that produce exactly esper mana! (None that produce esper + colorless)

Answer (score 3):

I found 97 matching cards [on Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aartifact+o%3A%2F%7BT%7D%3A.*%5Cbadd%5Cb.*%28%7B%5BWUB%5D%7D%7Cany%7Cthat%29%2F+f%3Acommander+ci%3Awub&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) using the following search

> `t:artifact o:/{T}:.*\badd\b.*({[WUB]}|any|that)/ f:commander ci:wub`

This finds artifact cards with `{T}:`, `add` and `{W}` or `{U}` or `{B}`, or the word `any` (for "any color") or `that` (for "that color", referring to an earlier choice), in that order, that are legal in commander, and have a color identity that matches white, blue, and/or black, so that they are playable in an Alela commander deck.

For cards that can tap for all of those colors instead of just some of them, [this search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aartifact%20o%3A%2F%7BT%7D%3A.*%5Cbadd%5Cb.*%28%28%7B%5BWUB%5D%7D.*%29%7B3%7D%7Cany%7Cthat%29%2F%20f%3Acommander%20ci%3Awub&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) finds 59 cards:

> `t:artifact o:/{T}:.*\badd\b.*(({[WUB]}.*){3}|any|that)/ f:commander ci:wub`

The difference is that this looks for three mana symbols that match `{W}`, `{U}`, or `{B}`. Technically this would also find cards that add {W}{W}{W}, but that doesn't actually come up.

Comment: Only one of those actually produces all three colors.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The question (even before editing) asked for "white blue **or** black" mana (my emphasis).

Comment: @PhilipKendall, do you mean like Indatha Crystal, which produces "W, B, *or* G"?  The examples the OP lists are all 3 color producers. I agree that the wording is open to interpretation, but it's clear that the OP is more interested in three color producers.

Comment: Note that this misses artifacts that produce mana of any color, such as Coalition Relic

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5Bm/%7B%e2%96%baUW%e2%97%84%7D/%5D+%5B%7BT%7D:%5D+%5BAdd%5D&type=+%5B%22Artifact%22%5D) is a Gatherer search for Artifacts that have a tapped ability and mention the word "add" and either white or blue mana. It looks like most of them involve mana abilities, which makes sense. Obviously some of these are not going to be appropriate for certain circumstances, and I make no claim as to which might be more easily obtainable than others. We can [refine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Bm/%7B%E2%96%BAUW%E2%97%84%7D/%5D%20%5B%7BT%7D:%5D%20%5BAdd%5D&type=%20%5B%22Artifact%22%5D&format=%20%5B%22Commander%22%5D) the search to only list cards which are legal for Commander, and it only takes about 3 entries of the list so there are still plenty of choices.